# Custom command line parameter for testing

Tags: django

I found a way to pass a custom parameter to Django testing from command line:

```
class TestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def __init__(self, option=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.browser = kwargs['browser']

    @classmethod
    def add_arguments(cls, parser):
        DiscoverRunner.add_arguments(parser)

        parser.add_argument('-br', '--browser', help='Browser test')

    def build_suite(self, test_labels=None, extra_tests=None, **kwargs):
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        suite.addTest(TestProjects('test_create_project'))
        return suite
```

But how can I get this parameter value inside my TestCase ?. Maybe a way is to pass self.browser parameter inside TestProjects class ? If yes how can I do that

Comment: What does this parameter do? Do you want to run or exclude certain tests when this parameter is passed? Could you add an example of how you would want to use it?

Comment: I want to use this parameter as a string to some complex frontend tests that I have. So I want to get this string.